# String matching in math expression x <= 900 (int, int)

Tags: java, regex

I have the number, say 900.
I extract a string with the format `"x <= int (int, int)"` for example. `"x <= 900 (4, 7)"`
I want to verify that it matches the format `"x <= 900 (int, int)"`

How can I do it using String pattern matchers?

I have tried the following so far, the result is false.

```
1)        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("x <= 900 (\\d, \\d)");
2)        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("x <= 900 ([0-9], [0-9])");

        String expectedString = "x <= 900 (4, 7)";

        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(expectedString);
        System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed - it seems perfectly clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses using backslashes (`\`) as they are regular expression metacharacters. To match one or more digits, use `\d+`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("x <= \\d+ \\(\\d+, \\d+\\)");
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://ideone.com/VaapAL)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the parenthesis - otherwise, it'll interpret everything inside the parenthesis as a group (instead of treating the parenthesis as a literal character like you want). Here's one I did (admittedly using .NET syntax, but it'll be similar for Java I think):

```
^x <= [0-9]+ \([0-9]+, [0-9]+\)$
```

NOTE: in the string, you'll likely need to escape the `\` too, so the string would be:

```
String regex = "^x <= [0-9]+ \\([0-9]+, [0-9]+\\)$:
```